# Documentation - copy or link to original project page?

Tags: discussion, documentation

For many languages and frameworks, there are extensive documentations out there. For example, got angular, there's a [whole site](https://angular.io/) telling the history, installation guide, APIs and starter projects for the angular framework.

What should be in the SO documentation? should I cut&paste from the original site or link to the site so the text will always up to date?

Comment: *"should I cut&paste from the original site"*: ___No___. That might not be legal at all. Also, there will be licensing issues. For example, the Qt documentation uses GFDL, but CC-BY-SA and GFDL aren't compatible.